# Posts is not defined in for loop

Tags: node.js, express, for-loop

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
let port = 8080;
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("views engine","ejs");
app.set("views",path.join(__dirname,"views"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));
let posts =[
    {username : "Naved",content  : "I love coding"},{username : "Noman",content  : "I love studying"}{username : "Saimoon",content  : "I love cooking"},] ;
app.get("/posts",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("index.ejs", {posts});
});
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`app is listening at the port ${port}`);
});
```

```
<body>
    <h1>Quora Posts</h1>
    <% for(post of Posts) { %>
        <div class="post">
            <h3 class="user">@ <%= post.username %></h3>
            <h4 class="content"><%= post.content %></h4>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</body>
```

index.ejs in index.ejs when i use for loop to render the info i am getting reference error posts is not defined but i define the array in index.js

Comment: Correct the variable name in your EJS. It is "posts" not "Posts".

Comment: thanx  a lot sir error resolved

Answer (score 1):

as [Sha'an](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11586487/shaan) already commented:

> Correct the variable name in your EJS. It is "posts" not "Posts".

JavaScript is case-sensitive. You are passing the array as `posts` (**p**), but you are trying to iterate over `Posts` (**P**):

```
<body>
    <h1>Quora Posts</h1>
    <% for(post of posts) { %>
        <div class="post">
            <h3 class="user">@ <%= post.username %></h3>
            <h4 class="content"><%= post.content %></h4>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</body>
```